# OpenTok Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok, tokbox

I am really hoping someone can help me. I am attempting to integrate OpenTok on my Ruby On Rails application on my already built app. I have used the following article to attempt the integration and to adapt it to my specific site. I've followed the step by step instruction here: https://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/video-chatting-in-ruby-on-rails/

I need help because I am currently getting the error message:

```
uninitialized constant OpenTok::OpenTokSDK
```

and it appears it is not authenticating with Tokbox.

Here is my code:

```
  def index
    @rooms = Room.where(:public => true).order("created_at DESC")
    @new_room = Room.new
  end

  def create
    session = @opentok.create_session request.remote_addr
    params[:room][:sessionId] = session.session_id

    @new_room = Room.new(params[:room])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_room.save
        format.html { redirect_to("/party/"+@new_room.id.to_s) }
      else
        format.html { render :controller => 'rooms',
          :action => "index" }
      end
    end
  end

  def party
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])

    @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token :session_id =>@room.sessionId     
  end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post you are following is a little outdated. You probably pulled down the latest version of the 'opentok' gem, so you need to update your code to use the latest API. Fortunately, there aren't too many changes, here are the updated methods:

```
def create
  session = @opentok.create_session
  params[:room][:sessionId] = session.session_id

  @new_room = Room.new(params[:room])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @new_room.save
      format.html { redirect_to(“/party/”+@new_room.id.to_s) }
    else
      format.html { render :controller => ‘rooms’, :action => “index” }
    end
  end
end

def party
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])

  @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token @room.sessionId 
end

def config_opentok
  if @opentok.nil?
    @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new YOUR_API_KEY, YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN
  end
end
```

For further reference, take a look at the [OpenTok Ruby SDK README](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ruby-sdk)

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thanks so much! I am still getting an error regarding the line {

  @new_room = Room.new(params[:room]) } Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For `{ @new_room = Room.new(params[:room]) }` you should change it to `@new_room=Room.new(room_params)` and create a private method like this:

```
def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(:name, :public, :sessionId)
end
```